# Executing a command over telnet

Tags: windows, remote, telnet

Is it possible to run an executable on a remote machine using telnet?

I connect to a windows XP machine via telnet and then I execute the exe by issuing this simple command.

`RunProgramme.exe`

No errors, but I don't think the program run as it does not create a directory which it should. If I remote in to the remote machine uisng RDP and execute the run the command in the same way directly it works!

I have turned off firewall and any antivrius but that didn't make a difference. What else should I do?

Comment: You may also be interested in [`psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553), which will allow remote execution of applications.

Comment: I am trying to switch away from psexec its caused me a lot of headache! Thanks for suggesting it though. Plus I need something universal so I can run commands on a linux box too.

Comment: On Linux the solution is definitively SSH! Using telnet as a "universal" for remote command execution system is pretty much unthinkable these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you thought of using SSH?  I know the Cygwin provides the SSH server and runs as a service.  Using SSH would be a better solution than using telnet, at minimum from a security point of view, and the fact that you can put a command on the SSH line to be run.

Comment: I second the SSH solution. If you don't like a Cygwin stack on your destination machine, you could try the CopSSH package (http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh).

Answer (score 1):

PSEXEC is the tool to use for this.  Not TELNET.  You say PSEXEC gave you a headache.  But TELNET clearly isn't working - give it another shot.

Comment: Or at least explain which headaches `telnet` will prevent.